Show that $f(\frac{1}{z})$ have a essential singularity at $0$.
We need to show that if $f(z)$ ,who is entire, periodic and non-constant , then $f(\frac{1}{z})$ have an essential singularity at 0.
So we then need to show that:

$f(\frac{1}{z})$ as not a pole at $z=0$
$f(\frac{1}{z})$ as not a removable singularity at $z=0$

For 1), as f(z) is periodic , $f(z+p)=f(z)$ for somme $p \in \mathbb{R}$,
then we can only take a sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{z_0+np}$ with $z_0=f(z_0)$
then : $$lim_{z\to0}|f(1/z)| = lim_{n\to\infty}|f(1/a_n)| $$
$$lim_{n\to\infty}|f(z_0+np)|=lim_{n\to\infty}|f(z_0)|$$
$$= |f(z_0)|  $$
So it's not a pole.
But how do we show 2) ?
We know that by Liouville theorem : A entire fonction who is bounded $\implies$ the fonction is constant. The fact that $f(z)$ is entire and non constant $\implies$ f(z) is not bounded. But is it enough to say that z=0 is not a removable singularity?
If yes , by wich theorem ?
Thanks in advance

Assume that $f(1/z)$ has removable singularity at $z=0$. Then we know that this can happen only if $f(1/z)$ is bounded near $z=0$. But this means $f(z)$ is a bounded entire function, hence is constant by Liouville's theorem.

But where did you use periodicity? See my answer for how that is an essential part of the reasoning

@random_0620 I believe we don't need periodicity to eliminate the removable case. The pole case Op already handled, and it used periodicity like you wanted.

Ah good point!! Very nice answer

$f(\frac  1 z) \to f(0)$ as $ |z|\to \infty$. If $f(\frac  1 z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$, then it extends to a bounded entire function. Hence, it would be  constant, by Liouville's Theorem.

Periodicty is not used for this  part. It is needed for showing that the singularity is not a pole. @random_0620

Yes, that's enough. If $z=0$ is removable for $f(1/z)$, then $f(1/z)$ is bounded around $0$, therefore $f$ is bounded around $\infty$, hence bounded over the whole $\mathbb C$.
To be a little bit more precise, by $z=0$ is removable, there exists an $\delta, \epsilon>0$ and $w$ such that whenever $0<|z|< \epsilon$, $|f(1/z)-w|\le \delta\Rightarrow|f(1/z)|<\delta+|w|=:M$.
Note that $0<|z|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow|\frac{1}{z}|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}=:R$, therefore we have $|f(z)|< M$ whenever $|z|> R$. Meanwhile, since $\{z:|z|\le R\}$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded over the disc. Therefore $f$ is bounded over $\{z:|z|> R \}\cup\{z:|z|\le R\}=\mathbb C$ which contradicts Liouvielle.

Since $f(z)$ is entire, we may write it as $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$. Since $f$ is non-constant, there is some $a_k\neq 0$ where $k>0$.
We will show infinitely many of the $a_k$ are non-zero. By contradiction, suppose finitely many $a_k$ were non-zero. Then the function would be a non-constant polynomial. Take a root $z_0$. Then $z_0+nw$ are infinitely many roots by periodicity contradicting the fundamental theorem of algebra.
Thus, we may conclude,
$$f(1/z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^0 a_{-k}z^k$$
has  an essential singularity because infinitely many terms of the Laurent series are non-zero.
